# (react-native realm) undefined is not an object (evaluating '_realm.Realm.schemaVersion')

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

I use realm(0.13.2) before with nothing wrong.
But when I update the plugin to realm(1.2.0),It happend:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_realm.Realm.schemaVersion')

configureRealm
configure.js:14:19
```

and configure.js,line 14:

```
var next = Realm.schemaVersion(Realm.defaultPath);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I find that realm has default export.
so,I just should change my import code

from
`import {Realm} from 'realm';` to 
`import Realm from 'realm';`